# Customizing @XmlAccessorType value generated using jaxb from xml schema

Tags: jaxb

I'm using JAXB to generate java files (code) from  XML schemas. The java files that are generated have the default @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) specified. I would like to change this so that the resultant java files have NONE access annotated ( @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) ) and not have the annotations generated at the field level. Is there a way to accomplish this via a custom bindings file?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm facing the same situation, and would appreciate to know how you solved it. Thanks